# How to access contentResolver of a fragment in a different activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

The situation is that I have a `MainFragment` (extends a `ListFragment`, implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`) which is called from `MainActivity`. A new activity `DetailsActivity` is called from that fragment to display the content of a certain item in a list view getting the id as an intent argument. How can I `getContentResolver()` to access its methods using a Uri?

The error right now I get from accessing content resolver is:

```
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.xxxx.words.contentprovider/words`

uri = Uri.parse(MainContentProvider.CONTENT_URI.toString());
            getContentResolver().insert(uri, contentValues);

CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + "com.xxxx.words.contentprovider" + "/" + "words");
```

android manifest file:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="com.xxxx.words.contentprovider.MainContentProvider"
        android:name=".contentprovider.MainContentProvider"/>
```

or should i just return a `Bundle` from that `DetailsActivity` and access the content provider in the initial fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error right now I get from accessing content resolver is

That is because your `Uri` does not match your `android:authorities`. Your `android:authorities` is `com.xxxx.words.contentprovider.MainContentProvider`. Your `Uri` uses `com.xxxx.words.contentprovider`. These are not the same, and they need to be the same.

Also, please add `android:exported` to your `<provider>`, set to `true` (if third-party apps should have complete access to the provider) or `false` (if they should not).

Answer (score 13):

Just simply use this:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

Answer (score 7):

For Java

`ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();`

For Kotlin

`private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer. Code only answer is discouraged and not helpful to get a full context of the solution for the developer community.

Comment: @iankits, sure but I was just following the structure of the other answers.

Comment: I didn't received other answers for review. They would have also received the same comments. Think of a new or novice programmer who needs a bit more than code like some explanation around it. Please do not follow the herd or bad examples. :)

Comment: @iankits, how would I expand on this answer?

Answer (score 3):

In `Activity` simply pass this,when `Fragment` pass `getActivity()`.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Declare variable in your fragment class :

```
private Context context;
```

2.Now In `onCreateView(inflator,container,savedInstanceState)`method of your fragment you will do following :

```
context = container.getContext();
```

3.Now you can call your `getContentResolver()` method or any method which you can call in your main activity can also be called here by using this `context` variable:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
```

Your code will look like this:

```
    public class your_fragment extends Fragment {

         private Context;

         @override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflator inflator,ViewGroup Container,Bundle savedInstancestate) 
         {
            context = container.getContext();
            View root = inflator.inflate(R.id.your_Layout_of_frag);
            return root;
            
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example works for Kotlin

```
 val resolver = context?.contentResolver?.openFileDescriptor(....)
```

Cheers!